# POST method adds a header to an xlsx file which corrupts it

Tags: python, api, flask, post

I'm trying to send an xlsx file using Python requests library. My request looks like this:

```
import requests

url_attachment = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/attachment"
payload={}
files=[('file',(filename, open(filename,'rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]
headers = {}
requests.request("POST", url_attachment, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

and my mock server looks like this:

```
import flask
from flask import request

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

@app.route('/api/attachment', methods=['POST'])
def get_file():
    data = request.files['file']
    data.save('the-file.xlsx')

    return "ok"



app.run()
```

The mock server works fine, and the file gets sent correctly.
However, when I call the actual API (that I have no access to), the file gets corrupted. The person who owns the API sent me the corrupted file, and after inspection I can see that the content got wrapped in this:

```
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="the-file.xlsx"; filename="the-file.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

//content

-------------------------------28947758029299--
```

Does someone have an idea why this is happening? What can I change in my function to stop this from happening? I have also tried changing the Content-Type to application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet  but apparently this results in the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved now. If anyone comes across a similar issue in the future, the cause was the receiving method in the API considering content as 'multi-part form data'.